# Trying to find a regex match for lowercase characters, but ignore first 11 characters

Tags: regex, bash, match, character

I've got a file with text like this...

```
0x8a1d4099 dfg-gw2
0x8da88e90 FVG-GW3
```

I want to write a bash script to look at the file, but only display the first line, not the second. I simply need to ignore the first 11 characters, and only match on the text that follows if it has lowercase characters.

Comment: You can share what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
^.{11}[^a-z]*[a-z]+
```

conceptually, this pattern skips 11 characters at the beginning of a line, matches an arbitrary number of non-lowercase characters finally matching at least 1 lowercase char. complement the first chracter class with characters you do not want to occur in matching line.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern like this should work:

```
^.{11,}[a-z].*$
```

Or if your engine supports Unicode character classes:

```
^.{11,}\p{Ll}.*$
```

Alternatively, if your engine supports lookaheads, you can use one of these:

```
^.{11}(?=.*[a-z]).*$
^.{11}(?=.*\p{Ll}).*$
```

Comment: (comment does not apply to the lookahead variation) this is a greedy prefix match, beware if the lines in your file max end in portions that should not take part in the test ( eg. if your file contains of 2 or space-separated entries and the lowercase test should only apply to the second part).

Comment: @collapsar I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. Both patterns will match only if a lower-case letter appears after the 11th character in the line. Which is exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: the OP wrote 'only match on the text that follows' which i feel might mean 'non-WS text that follows'. otherwise you're right of course